# How do I pack textures for sending off to a render farm

Tags: rendering, texturing

Whenever i try to send a project off to a render farm such as sheepit, it says it needs the textures packing with the file in order to render correctly.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to File-Exernal Data-Pack All into blend.
[image]