# Face Selection Masking for Painting overlaped by the texture

Tags: texture-painting

Doing the Piero Course, when it comes to paint the textures in the model direct in the Texture Paint mode, when setting the **Face Selection Masking for Painting**, the overlaping wire frame won't show. Some regions like the eye and the fingers of the model show white lines that resembles the wire but only in these regions:

[image]

Is there a additional configuration that I'm missing so I can paint with these wire outlines? The .blend file is [in this link](http://we.tl/lj2QVXOvxv).

**Edit: Packed .blend file with textures and updated the link.**

Comment: There are no textures in your .blend. Please pack the textures (http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30906/how-do-i-pack-textures-for-sending-off-to-a-render-farm) and upload a file again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry, but since the ***Blender 2.73*** version release you can't display the wire outlines while painting.

[image]

***''Paint mask selection now only shows selection boundary (so you can better see what you are painting)''***, as you can read in this manual: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.73/Painting

Comment: Only workaround I have is by using a second UV map of an image texture that is a square with 0 alpha except for lines painted at the edges - this is then placed in the slot below the main painting texture, and with a standard UV reset, the wires are then visible but you can limit paint to the selected face and selected texture slot.