# Vertex color problem

Tags: cycles-render-engine, vertices, color

**Here is the model:** https://p3d.in/g7qa3

**Problem:** there is a vertex color applied to the middle ship's mesh. It came after I added the first material (the windows texture/material).

**More information:**
- I am using Cycles Render and UV mapping is done there;
- Ship is black, because the first material texture I added has black and white contents;
- When I first load a material, it seems to color the mesh in a random hue from its own color content;
- I have not used anything else (like vertex painting and such), all color diffusions are set to white as default;

**How do I remove this nasty vertex coloring, while keeping my UV map and materials intact?**

P.S. here is the file: [image]

Comment: Attach your files here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @atek done, here is the blend file

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you could add screenshots to indicate specifically what problem you are referencing in your question as just by looking at your blend file it is unclear. Also, the textures are not included in the blend - they need to be 'packed', see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30906/how-do-i-pack-textures-for-sending-off-to-a-render-farm

Comment: @b0b1man WHat are you trying to achieve with vertex groups?

Comment: When you look at the 3 models in the p3d link, the middle one has black coloring on its non-textured faces. This is the color that came after I imported the first material in Cycles Render.

The question is, why in the world is this happening? Cant Blender just not color the vertices like that when adding materials?

To replicate this, just get a box, go into cycles render, make new material and put an image texture to it. Now, under Texture View, the mesh will have taken on a color from the material, without even UVmapping the object!