# New to texturing, my leather texture is see-through

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

i have been playing around with leather textures and i decided to make a chair, this is a test render of it:

[image]

As you can see, the seat itself is transparent. I have read some answers on this type of issue, but they were not what i was looking for. I'm sure this has something to do about texturing.

Here is the node setup:

[image]

Green: COLOR TEXTURE
Red: DISPLACEMENT TEXTURE
Blue: NORMAL TEXTURE

Comment: By default, images used  on projects are not saved as part of the .blend file. You have to pack them otherwise they just live in your computer and no one can access them but you. Use FIle>External Data>Pack all into file. Then save the file again.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't pack your textures, we cant troubleshoot material problems without all the relevant textures.

Anyway this doesn't look like a texture problem, not even material related.

You have lots of duplicated geometry and overlapping vertex in your mesh, there are double faces everywhere in your seat, and your.

Enter *Edit Mode* in each of your meshes, select everything then press <kbd>W</kbd> > *Remove Doubles*.

Be sure to recalculate normals afterwards by selecting everything and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

Comment: it makes the seat into a circle... and whenever a strectch it out it goes back into being transparent @Duarte Farrajota Ramos

Comment: for the seat i scaled a cube and added a subdivision surface modifier, then in edit mode i stretched it out into a box shape again.

Comment: Yes it does, if you want to *Subdivision Surface* an object, while keeping hard edges you have to learn how to use what are usually called **Control Loops**, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6425/keep-sharp-edges-when-using-subdivision-surface

Comment: i did i used Control+R to make loop cups to create a box shape again.

Comment: Loops shouldn't overlap the existing edges, they can be close to them but not coinciding.

Comment: well, they overlapped for me :)

Comment: not sure what i exactly did wrong.

Comment: still not resolved @Duarte Farrajota Ramos

Comment: I think you've got all the data to solve this already. It is clearly a normals problem, eliminating duplicate geometry and cleaning up your model with proper modelling topology seems to solve the transparency issue. Without proper file with packed textures there not much more I can say

Comment: i still don't understand. you are telling me to remove doubles and recalculate normals. if i did not word what i did properly, i scaled a cube on the z axis, then i turned on smooth shading, then turned on subdivision surface modifier and went into edit mode and added a couple loop cuts. i will add a nodes setup @Duarte Farrajota Ramos

Comment: Packed the texture, hope it worked :)

Comment: Do you know what a file with packed textures it means? See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30906/how-do-i-pack-textures-for-sending-off-to-a-render-farm . In fact don't bother, this has probably nothing to do with textures themselves. Like I said, you mesh has overlapping geometry, get rid of it and add new edge loops that don't overlap with existing ones. If you have any modelling questions ask a new question, this is out of scope for solving here in the comment. See the linked answer in the comment above.

Comment: i don't know how to make it not overlap....