# Why can I only texture paint some parts of my model?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

[image]

I am not able to paint on the whole model. I tried many times but nothing worked.

[image]

Comment: no I can paint on some surfaces as you can see on the pic but it doesn't allow me to paint on some others ;(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several issues with your file, all contributing to not being able to paint on all your model:

### Materials

The material that is displayed in the viewport is only applied to a few of the faces in your model (the ones you can paint on). Go into *Edit Mode*, select all faces in your model by pressing <kbd>A</kbd> once or twice, select 'Material' in the list of materials and click *Assign* in the material panel:

[image]

Based on your specific file, the object should now be black.

### Normals

Still in *Edit Mode* we can address the second problem.

Some of the faces in your mesh are inside out. This is due to having internal faces inside your model, which confuses Blender into not knowing whether a face is inside your model or out. A quick fix for this is to open the *Properties* panel in the *3D View* (press <kbd>N</kbd> to open it), navigate to the *Mesh Display* panel, turn on *Face Normals* (the cube icon) and increase the size a bit:

[image]

This displays the face direction in the viewport in the form of a line coming out of the centre of a face. The 'direction' a face is pointing is called its 'Normal'. Any faces that don't have a line coming out of their centre are inside out.

The faces I have selected here are inside out:

[image]

Select them, press <kbd>Space</kbd> and search for 'Flip Normals' and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Their 'normal' direction has been flipped and they should now have lines coming out of them showing the direction they are facing (outwards). The lines were there previously, but they were pointing inside the model.

### Face Selection Masking

The third problem is that you have 'Face Selection Masking' enabled in the *3D View* header, meaning only faces that are selected in *Edit Mode* can be painted:

[image]

Either deselect the 'Face Selection Masking' option or select all faces before starting to paint.

Comment: does not work at all!!! I did what you told me and still the same issue... ;((((

Comment: Upload your file to [here](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), making sure to [pack your textures](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30906/how-do-i-pack-textures-for-sending-off-to-a-render-farm) (save the file afterwards) then use the 'edit' link under your question to add the embed code it gives you.

Comment: here is it: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4605" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4605/)

Comment: try painting on parts like the windshield or the hood, some areas work but some don't

Comment: @iAlbert180 I have updated the answer, but I'm not sure if it will solve your problem as you didn't pack the textures like I suggested in my previous comment.

Comment: I did that and not i cannot paint on the hole model even tho on the UV map it shows and now I have some sort of line going on my brush

Comment: @iAlbert180 I can't help you if you don't upload a blend file with packed textures.  In one of my previous comments there is a link showing you how to do this. Save the file after packing textures, re-upload it and use the edit link under your question to add the new embed code.

Comment: I uploaded it again, with packed textures and

Comment: @iAlbert180 I have updated my answer. I do those *exact* steps on your file and I can paint on all of it.