# materials modification after changing render engine

Tags: rendering

i have imported some animated characters in blender from mixamo they were originally makehuman characters which i added them animation by mixamo i used cycle   engine for rendering the results was satisfying

[image]

but after several days when i tried to render them again all materials had turned purple.
[image]

i don't know why it has been changed !!

Comment: The purple is a default warning color indicating missing textures .. your Blend file has lost track of the external files. After finding them manually, and reloading them, you have the option of [packing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/30907/35559) them into your .blend file, if you don't mind the resulting file size.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are all the textures in my file pink?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5368/why-are-all-the-textures-in-my-file-pink)