# Weird gaps in mask texture painting

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, uv, node-editor, texture-painting

I'm trying to paint a terrain mesh with multiple textures using a node setup involving masks, the problem is... Something is not letting me paint on these parts (where the rock texture is) The plains leave weird gaps, the mountains and coasts I can't paint at all. Any Ideas? This is driving me crazy.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It can be more things, would be fastest to attach blend https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ if its big file cut a mesh and send just a part with issue persistting.

Comment: Yeah, I should have done that from the get-go. I've attached the file now.

Comment: please https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/30907/2214 without textures quite hard so say

Comment: My bad, I never had to share a blend file before so getting used to the process, now it should be fixed.

Comment: Im not sure yet, but since you set Subsurf modifier to 11 also for viewport you can draw without gaps. Will check later.

Comment: Huh, that's interesting, just tested it out, It seems that whenever there's a steep enough angle it doesn't paint the texture. Still, no idea what might be causing this since I haven't masked anything based on height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uf ...

- **Apply Scale** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> ... fixed painting, brush skipped all parts with even minimum slope.

[image]

Since painting worked fine without Displacement modifier I was just curious why you used *Strength* 3000 for such contrast displace map (usually 1 is more than enough). Than I saw your Scale ratio Terrain 7500 / 4500 / 1.

If you try to set Scale 1/1/1, you can see why brush could not handle that :)
Faces are too steep in original ratio. Brush probably thinks faces are on side or squeezed in such a small place to detect or what ever. Scale ratio cause quite a lot of issues in general.

[image]

BTW - the similar extreme is use for mesh as a one face for such kind of subdivision, I would suggest subdivide id few times in edit mode (first Ctrl+R to add loopcut in a midle so subdivision faces are square, not rectangle)

[image]

Comment: And... It's fixed :D Now I can clearly see the danger of crazy scale values... Oh, and I had to put the displacement strength to 300 because that's the only way it was strong enough, otherwise it was just too low for my purposes, I found that weird too, generally that slider is so sensitive! Anyway, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: 300 is probably correct, since your Dimension is almost 18 km wide.